# How to create dynamic colspan table in javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, html-table, react-bootstrap

How to generate dynamic colspan table from json data in javascript react.
In obj,

w1,w2 represents the groupheader,
t1,t2 represents header

for each item, display the data according to time which is grouped by week,
any libraries or any possible way to create ,
I really got stuck.

```
var obj =  {
  options: {
    w1: {start:"sep",end: "6"},
    w2: {start:"nov", end: "5"}
  },
  intervals: {
    t1: {begin: "1", end: "2", totalqty: 2,totalamt: 200},
    t2: {begin: "4", end: "7", totalqty: 3, totalamt: 300},
  }
  items: [
    {
      name: "s1",
      desc: "sample1",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 100},t2: {qty:1, amt: 200}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:1, amt: 100},t2: {qty:2, amt: 200}}
    }
    {
      name: "s2",
      desc: "sample2",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 100},t2: {qty:0, amt: 0}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 0},t2: {qty:1, amt: 200}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Ouput
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-resonance-9s2wx?file=/src/App.js). It does not focus on styling, but rather on generating the rows.

I've added comments where I thought it might be necessary, I'll update my answer if there's something unclear.

Few things to note:

- I've used array indices for key properties wherever there's an array, but that's just
  for demo purposes. Read more about [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) here and think
  of selecting appropriate ID.
- I used `Object.values` to make it a bit more clear, but if you
  need to support IE you'll need to rewrite it to `Object.keys` and `Array.map` or
  something else. Check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values).
- I've hardcoded the `colspan` of the interval header to 4, but
  it's not a big deal making it dynamic, I think.
- Inside **ItemRow** component I flattened a little bit the structure
  so that it's easier to use and more readable. **So I've tried to
  strike a balance between readability and performance.** If this is
  part of some performance-critical functionality, you might want to
  measure and optimize further.

Comment: thnks for the solution, can you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097391/how-to-loop-through-object-and-arrays-and-create-new-object-javascript/63097806#63097806