# How to loop through object and arrays and create new object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested-object

I would like to know to how to change the object to new array of object in javascript
How to loop through object and arrays and create new object javascript.
I have object `obj`,

`group` key represents the weeks (start-end),

in `columns` array, should create a arraylist of
each

item description as value and desc as col,

intervals(begin-end) as col and value as qty
finalqty key as col and value as finalqty value
finalamt key as col and value as finalamt value
(ie)per week

```
function newObj(obj){
 var result = obj.products.map(e=>({
     group: Object.values(obj.options).map((opt, index) =>opt.start+"-"+opt.end),
     columns: [{
       col: "desc",
      value: e.desc}
    ]

  }))
}


const obj =  {
  options: {
    w1: {start:"Jan",end: "1"},
    w2: {start:"Feb", end: "1"}
  },
  intervals: {
    t1: {begin: "1", end: "2", totalqty: 2,totalamt: 200},
    t2: {begin: "4", end: "7", totalqty: 3, totalamt: 300}
  },
  items: [
    {
      name: "s1",
      desc: "sample1",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1},finalqty:4,finalamt:300},
      w2: {t1: {qty:1},t2: {qty:2},finalqty:6,finalamt:400}
    },
    {
      name: "s2",
      desc: "sample2",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:0}, finalqty:5,finalamt:100},
      w2: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1}, finalqty:8,finalamt:70}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
[
[
  {
    group:"Jan 1", // represents w1
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
      value: 'sample1' // item.desc
      },    
      {
       col: '1-2', // represents t1
       value: 0   , // represents t1.qty
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', // represents t2   
       value: 1 // represents w1.t2.qty   
      } ,{
       col: "finalqty",
       value: 4
      },
      {
       col: "finalamt",
       value: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    group:"Feb 1", // represents w2
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
      value:'sample1' 
      },
      {
      col: '1-2', // represents t1
        value:1   , // represents t1.qty
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', // represents t2
        value:2 ,// represents t2.qty
      },
      ,{
       col: "finalqty",
       value: 6
      },
      {
       col: "finalamt",
       value: 400
      }
   ]
  },
  {
   group:"Jan 1", 
    columns: [
      {
      col: 'desc',
       value:'sample2' 
      },    
      {
      col: '1-2', 
        value:0, 
      },
      {
       col: '4-7', 
        value:0 
      } 
      ,{
       col: "finalqty",
       value: 5
      },
      {
       col: "finalamt",
       value: 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   group:"Feb 1",
    columns: [
      {
     col: 'desc',
       value:'sample2' 
      },
      {
       col: '1-2',
        value:0   ,
      },
      {
       col: '4-7',
        value:1,
      },
      {
       col: "finalqty",
       value: 8
      },
      {
       col: "finalamt",
       value: 70
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to explain the **approach/algorithm** to solve the problem. So that it might help you to solve the similar problems in future

```js
// Declare an empty array
const results = [];

/* Since you need result as input object weeks x 2 times (4 objects in output array)
 * We need to perform outer loop with the obj.items
 * Inner loops with interval/options combination
 * Push the final value to results
*/
for (... of obj.items) { // 2 iterations
  // Declare an array with data needed from items
  const columns = [...];
  // Collect the data from items in object
  for (... in obj.intervals) {
    // Collect the data from interval and add it to columns
  }
  for (... in obj.options) { // 2 iterations
    // Collect data from options
    const output = {...};
    // Add columns collected above to output
    // Push the final output to results
    results.push(output); // 4 objects in output at the end
  }
}
```

---

#### Updated the actual code answer with above approach (`With little improvisation as per requirement`)

```js
const obj =  {
  options: {
    w1: {start:"Jan",end: "1"},
    w2: {start:"Feb", end: "1"}
  },
  intervals: {
    t1: {begin: "1", end: "2", totalqty: 2, totalamt: 200},
    t2: {begin: "4", end: "7", totalqty: 3, totalamt: 300}
  },
  items: [
    {
      name: "s1",
      desc: "sample1",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1}, finalqty:4, finalamt:300},
      w2: {t1: {qty:1},t2: {qty:2}, finalqty:6, finalamt:400}
    },
    {
      name: "s2",
      desc: "sample2",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:0}, finalqty:5, finalamt:100},
      w2: {t1: {qty:0},t2: {qty:1}, finalqty:8, finalamt:70}
    }
  ]
}

const results = [];

for(let item of obj.items) {
  for(let opt in obj.options) {
    const columns = [{col: 'desc', value: item.desc}];

    for (let key in obj.intervals) {
      columns.push({
        col: `${obj.intervals[key].begin}-${obj.intervals[key].end}`,
        value: item[opt][key].qty
      });
    }

    results.push({
      group: `${obj.options[opt].start} ${obj.options[opt].end}`,
      columns: columns.concat([{
        col: 'finalqty',
        value: item[opt].finalqty
      },
      {
        col: 'finalamt',
        value: item[opt].finalamt
      }])
    });
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Updated my answer with the code. I would highly recommend you to give a try with the approach suggested and validate your answer and check what has been missed.

Comment: @codecat, Please post your answer if you found any better approach to this question so that it help others with the similar requirement.

Comment: jus one more help, for each interval list , have added finalqty and finalmt, need to include col, value , i have tried in my fiddle, but not working , please help https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/zsfky8j6/4/

Comment: Updated the answer. Please validate.

Comment: @codecat, If you feel the answer solved your problem, please try accepting it or try posting your answer which you felt the best for this question. Either of the step would help others who are facing similar issues. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks alot  for providing solution.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through objects and arrays use 'for' loop.

Oject = for/in ; Array = for/of

This explains it: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

For the first part of the question ("I would like to know to how to change the object to new array of object in javascript") could you please be more precise?